# после: after vs since

Tags: перевод, словоупотребление

In the following sentences, would *после* translate into English as *since*, or *after*? How can one tell?

```
В Пентагоне эти самолеты называют лучшими после F-22.

Stern также очень лестно отозвался о достоинствах Су-35,
назвав его лучшим истребителем после американского F-22.
```

(Edit: For context, here's the [source article](http://www.bbc.com//russian/international/2016/02/160202_russian_warplanes_syria) over at bbc.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sample, "после" is probably short form of "после того, как был представлен". However, it's not absolutely clear without full context, "лучший после" might also refer to a second place in competition.

I suppose that "после" should be translated as "since", because Google says that Су-35 is ten years newer than F-22.

Comment: Thanks Надежда, Nikolay, and V.V. - based on your replies, I agree that _since_ is most likely. It looks like the meaning really is ambiguous without context, so I'll stop feeling sooo silly for asking :)

Answer (score 5):

The original quote in German reads:

> Obwohl die Sukhoi Su-35S auf einem alten Modell aus der UDSSR basiert, gilt sie als gefährlichstes Kampfflugzeug der Welt – wenn man vom US-Jet F-22 Raptor absieht

which I believe means

> Despite being based on an older Soviel model, the SU-35s is considered the most threatening fighter aircraft in the world, except for United States' F-22 "Raptor".

So I think in this context *лучший после* means "the second best after", not "the best since".

Answer (score 1):

http://gizmodo.com/b-2-spirit-americas-best-airplane-since-the-sr-71-1601310730

После is used in this meaning and should be translated as since.

Answer (score 0):

After.

"Since" would be **со времён** + genitive.

EDIT: V.V.'s link seems to strongly suggest it was "since" after all in the original English quote. If that's the case, I find **после** a questionable, if not downright sloppy, choice on the part of the Russian translator.

Answer (score 0):

После means "Compared to" particularly in this case.
Roughly, this meaning is influenced by envision of 1st and 2nd place on sport podiums. 2nd place runner is slower после 1st place.